# Operator Overloading in Binary Tree

Tags: c++, tree, operator-overloading, binary-tree

I am writing various operator overloads for a binary tree function that I am creating, the specifications require an overload for copying one tree to another.

```
binary_tree& binary_tree::operator=(const binary_tree &other)
{

return binary_tree();
}
```

the test for the operator working is as follows,

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
tree = new binary_tree(vector<int>{11, 5, 3, 7});
binary_tree temp = *tree;
temp.insert(12);
str = temp.inorder();
if (str != string("3 5 7 11 12") && temp.inorder() != tree->inorder())
    cerr << "test failed (assignment operator)" << endl;
else
    cout << "test passed (assignment operator)" << endl;
}
```

Obviously the point of this test is to create a new tree temp, which has the values of the original, but I can't seem to get it to work so that when .insert(12) is called, it doesn't alter the original tree. The operator has to work based on the test given in main, unedited.

I have tried various things inside the = operator but none of them seem to have any effect. I have methods such as,

```
void binary_tree::copyTree(node *& tree2, node *& tree)
{   
if(tree == NULL)
{
    tree2 = NULL;
}
else
{
    tree2 = new node;
    tree2->data = tree->data;

    copyTree(tree2->left, tree->left);
    copyTree(tree2->right, tree->right);
}
}
```

but using them hasn't seemed to do anything useful.

Comment: Show us something you've tried. Just saying "I've tried lots of things and they didn't work; please write my code for me" rarely goes down well here, I'm afraid.

Comment: A binary tree class, not a function; the assignment operator should return a reference to "self"; etc. etc.

Comment: *I have tried various things inside the = operator but none of them seem to have any effect*. Of course,  `binary_tree temp = *tree;` it's not calling the assignment operator, but the copy constructor.

Comment: @blazs `self` is Python. You mean `this`.

Comment: Almost certainly this doesn't work: `tree = new binary_tree(vector<int>{11, 5, 3, 7}); binary_tree temp = *tree;`

Comment: well for example
     binary_tree& binary_tree::operator=(const binary_tree &other)
     {
 tree = new node; 
 tree2 = other.tree;
 
 copyTree(tree, tree2);
 
 //binary_tree temp = new binary_tree(*tree2);
 //cout << "test" << endl;
 return tree; 
      }

but the issue is that it must return type binary tree and not type *node

Comment: Also there's a lot of leaking memory here.

Answer (score 2):

All your attempts will fail if you try to return by reference a local object of the operator

```
binary_tree& binary_tree::operator=(const binary_tree &other)
{
    ...
    return binary_tree();    // <=== ouch:  the reference will be invalid !
}
```

For assignment operator you'd better return the reference of the current tree:

```
binary_tree& binary_tree::operator=(const binary_tree &other)
{
    ...            // make your copy here 
    return *this;  
}
```

Now to implement your copying you could consider reuse your `binary_tree::copyTree()`.  Assuming you have a `node* root` in your tree, it would be something like:

```
binary_tree& binary_tree::operator=(const binary_tree &other)
{
    copyTree (root, other.root);  
    return *this;  
}
```